# Finding capitalized characters and printing their position & ASCII value

Tags: strings, common-lisp

I was trying to find out if a string contained a capitalized letter and if it did I wanted to know the position of the character and its ASCII code. I might have refactored a little to much.

Given an input such as:

> ```
> (is-capitalized "Meow mEow kItus kaTus")
> ```

My function returns:

> ```
> ((18 . 84) (11 . 73) (6 . 69) (0 . 77))
> ```

where the car of each sublist is the position in the string and the CDR of the sublist is the character ASCII code.

Given an input such as:

> ```
> (is-capitalized "omg my cat attacked my face.")
> ```

My function returns: NIL

So I guess it works for what I want but I feel like I reinvented so many things.

How can I improve this code?

```
(defun string-to-ascii (str)
    "Converts string of characters into a list of ascii character codes                                
       Returns list of ascii character codes"
      (loop
           :for i
         :in (coerce str 'list)
         :collect (char-code i)
         :into numbers
         :finally (return numbers)))

(defun return-capital-positon (list)
  "Returns list of positions where capitalized characters appear"
  (loop
       :for i
     :in list
     :collect (if (and (> i 65) (< i 90))
                  (position i list)
                  )))

(defun capital-hash (list-1 list-2 &key (test 'eql))
  "Return hash table where key: list-1 :pair list-2"
  (assert (= (length list-1)
              (length list-2)))
  (let ((table (make-hash-table :test test :size (length list-1))))
    (map nil (lambda (k v) (setf (gethash k table) v))
         list-1 list-2)
    table))

(defun do-hash (str)
  "Returns a hash table of key: position in string :pair ascii code character"
  (capital-hash
   (return-capital-positon
    (string-to-ascii str))
   (string-to-ascii str)))

(defun hash-table-alist (table)
  "Returns an association list containing the keys and values of hash table TABLE."
  (let ((alist nil))
    (maphash (lambda (k v)
               (push (cons k v)
                      alist)) table) alist))

(defun is-capitalized (str)
  "Returns a list of sublists in the form:                                                         
   ((position in string . ascii code of character)...)                                             
   if string contains capitalized characters                                                       
   otherwise returns nil"
  (remove 'nil (hash-table-alist (do-hash str)) :key #'first))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nits

Check out [`map`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map.htm):

```
(def string-to-ascii (str)
  (map 'list 'char-code str))
```

Note that [`<`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) takes `&rest` so you can write `(< 65 i 90)` instead of `(and (> i 65) (< i 90))` (you also want `<=` instead).

Furthermore, `return-capital-positon` is *quadratic* in length of the input string - it can be made *linear* instead.

`do-` is a usually used as a prefix for iteration macros.
Also, you call `string-to-ascii` in `do-hash` twice; you can use `let` to remove one call.

Your line breaks in `hash-table-alist` are *very* confusing.

You can use [`delete`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) instead of `remove` in `is-capitalized` because `hash-table-alist` returns a fresh list.

### Summary

I think your code is overkill.

```
(defun is-capitalized (str)
  (loop for char across str for code = (char-code char) for pos upfrom 0
     when (<= 65 code 90)
     collect (cons pos code)))
```

This has the added benefit that the return value increases in `pos` (i.e., it returns the [`reverse`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) of your function).

Alternatively, you can actually avoid constants:

```
(defun is-capitalized (str)
  (loop for char across str for pos upfrom 0
    when (char= char (char-upcase char))
    collect (cons pos (char-code char))))
```